# How do you initialize the MapScanCursor in Lettuce Redis client library?

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I am trying to do an HSCAN using Lettuce's synchronous commands. The problem is that I can't figure out the correct way of initializing the MapScanCursor. I've had no success with the constructor, and `MapScanCursor.INITIAL` gives type `ScanCursor` (no luck casting that to `MapScanCursor` either).

Here is an example:

```
RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create("redis://" + url + ":" + port);
RedisHashCommands<String, String> redisCommands = redisClient.connect().sync();
List<String> fields = new LinkedList<>();

MapScanCursor<String, String> scanCursor = ?

do {
    scanCursor = redisCommands.hscan(key, scanCursor);
    fields.addAll(scanCursor.getMap().keySet());
} while (!scanCursor.isFinished());
```

How should I initialize "scanCursor"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

To answer your question, initialize `scanCursor` with just `hscan(key)`.

```
MapScanCursor<String, String> scanCursor = null;

do {
    if (scanCursor == null) {
        scanCursor = redisCommands.hscan(key);
    } else {
        scanCursor = redisCommands.hscan(key, scanCursor);
    }
    fields.addAll(scanCursor.getMap().keySet());
} while (!scanCursor.isFinished());
```

Alternatively, you can use `ScanIterator` (see Lettuce 4.4) which is an `Iterator` and covers the complexity of Redis `SCAN` usage:

```
ScanIterator<KeyValue<String, String>> iterator = ScanIterator.hscan(redisCommands, key);

while (iterator.hasNext()) {

    KeyValue<String, String> next = iterator.next();
    // …
}
```

**Update**

Updated the `do…while`-based approach according to tcfritchman's comment.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer with an excellent alternative. This fixed my problem. One small issue though is that when using the first option, you must do the check for `!scanCursor.isFinished()` before calling `hscan` a second time. Otherwise you will get an error if the scan finishes on the first call. Eg. `scanCursor = redisCommands.hscan(key); while (!scanCursor.isFinished()) {scanCursor = redisCommands.hscan(key, scanCursor); fields.addAll(scanCursor.getMap().keySet()); }`